# Using a responsive slideshow as full-sized webpage background via html/javascript

Tags: javascript, image, background, slideshow, responsive

guys!

I am working on a project for my portfolio that I think would be absolutely sweet with the following feature: A responsive slideshow, fit to the browser that is made of clickable images that link you to more information about the specific product.

This idea was inspired by Triumph's home page (as of 2/16/17) here: http://www.triumphmotorcycles.com/

With that being said, I have selected several nice images that will fit the entire browser (though they are all not the same size). I used them to create a slideshow with Javascript (I want to use an array for the images just to get used to good habit) and set the height to 400x400px just to get a feel for creating the slideshow. It works great! Now it it is time to get this slideshow to fit the browser nice and neatly like Triumph's site! :)

[Here is a screenshot of their homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VQqj.jpg)
Here is my code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var image1=new Image();
            image1.src="Africa Twin Mountainside.jpg";
            var image2=new Image();
            image2.src="FZ-10.jpg";
            var image3=new Image();
            image3.src="GSXR track.jpg";
            var image4=new Image();
            image4.src="Pioneer 1k mountain.jpg";
            var image5=new Image();
            image5.src="Raptor sand.jpg";
        </script>           





        <img src="Africa Twin Mountainside.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400" alt=""/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var step=1;
            function slideit(){
            document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<5)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);                
             }
            slideit();            
        </script>
```

My current objective is to fit the images responsively to the browser window. To create a non scrolling, nice, slideshow background. Any help with fitting this to the browser window would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers from Texas! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script loops through all urls in the `images` array:

```js
// List your image urls
var images = [
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png",
]

// Array indexes start with 0
var step=0;
function slideit(){
  // set the src of the image tag to the url from the array
  var imageUrl = images[step];
  document.getElementById('slide').src = imageUrl;
  // count up
  step++;
  // reset if the end of the array was reached
  if(step>=images.length)
    step=0;
  // and repeat
  setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);                
}
slideit();
```

```html
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" id="slide" width="400" height="400" alt=""/>
```

Or to set the image to your page background:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageUrl + ')';
```

But then you'll want to set some css attributes to disable repeat and resize it to 100%.

Please be more specific on your next question.

Comment: I have most of it set-up, but the slideshow is not playing anymore though I am still tinkering. I really like this method and would like to get it down for future use. I know that I am doing something wrong but have not found it yet.

Comment: Got it working and I now understand the function and array due to you taking the time to help. Thank you!